# In time or On time?

Tags: grammaticality

Which is the correct way of saying:

> Do (sthg) ***on*** your free time.

or

> Do (sthg) ***in*** your free time.

Both variations are being used a lot.

Comment: When to use 'in time' and when 'on time' I feel sure is better suited to EL&L site.

Comment: There is a difference between them. Suggesting migration to [ell.se].

Comment: In this use, either sounds correct to me. I disagree that this is a question for EL&L.

Comment: @Mike Can you cite an example of on your free time being used appropriately?  I agree with the other two, better for ELL (this is a basic distinction in English!)

Comment: @David M. I would use either on or in my free time as above.  I avoid being proscriptive about speech, but I can't think of a reason why "in my free time" is required. Perhaps this is the result of my California/Tennessee/ Indiana influences or just because I come from not particularly educated people.  I disagree that it is a basic distinction in spoken English, but perhaps there is some grammar rule that makes it so for written English?  My apologies for being a dissenter, I'm really not trying to be contrary.

Comment: @Mike No apologizing for your background, that's never necessary in life. I would take a look at Susan's answer below, though.  I can say I've not heard the construct *on your free time*,  *on your own time* certainly.  Why the difference, I cannot tell you.

Comment: @Mike [Ngram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+your+free+time%2C+in+your+free+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20your%20free%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20your%20free%20time%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*on your*  **own**  *time* is common, and commonly understood to mean *don't do it while getting paid for doing something else.*

> “Do it on your own cell phone and *do it on your own time*.” – State Senator John Sampson to NY City and state employees

Do it **in your own time* means to do it at a pace which is comfortable to you. It is sometimes used sarcastically to mean *you're taking too long*; especially when using *sweet*:

> You can't take someone's money to train their horse and **do it in your own sweet time**, when you feel like it or when you've got nothing else to ...

*do it* **in** *your free time* is common, and means time other than *while getting paid for doing something else* or time *dedicated/set aside to do pre-arranged tasks*

> You can do it *in your free time*, but right now, you have chores to do.

The phrase *on your free time* is not commonly used; in fact, I have never heard it.